# Compare value with a DataType to see if it accepted

Tags: vb.net, types

### Issue

---

I have a method that is used to check values to see if they are accepted by the DataType in the database column.

I have a list of values which will be added to the database and also a list of DataType's from the table they will be added to, and i want to make sure that when I run a Stored Procedure to add the values that the values are correct.

### Code

---

```
Private Function CheckAllDataTypes(FormattedDate As String, sString As String(), file As FileInfo) As Boolean

    Using dbConn As RgsDb2.DbConnection = DataConnections.DbConnection()
        TableDataTypes = DataConnections.ExecuteQuery_SingleResultSetWithParams("sellTableDataTypes", dbConn, Params)
    End Using

    For Each item As String In sString
        //I WANT TO COMPARE THE VALUES IN SSTRING TO TABLEDATATYPES.
    Next

End Function
```

### Example

---

So lets see the table columns that I am wanting to add to are *int,varchar,varchar* and the values in **sString** are *3,"testing",3*.

This should fail as 3 is not a string.

Comment: But how would you separate the numerical 3 from the string "3" when you operate with a string variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex in your testing loop to check for numbers as strings if you don't want to consider them as a string.

Integers can be strings so you will also need to check for it being "alone" as it were. You might say that 3 should not be treated as a string but you would be hard pressed to say that "te5t1ng" shouldn't be treated 100% as a string.